# How can you read an array field from firestore, and an element to it, and save it back to firestore in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-cloud-firestore

I only want to retrieve a field which is an array from a document in firestore and I will add an element to it and update that array back to document. I'm using C#(Xamarin.Android).

I have tried to cast the data I'm getting from the firestore, but it throws an exception or arrayList is just null. I have global variable `ArrayList invitesArrayList;` then inside `OnSuccess` method I do this

`invitesArrayList = new ArrayList();`

1st option

```
var invites = item.Get("invites");
invitesArrayList = (ArrayList)invites;
```

> //exception, Specified cast is not valid

2nd option

`invitesArrayList = item.Get("invites") as ArrayList;`

> //exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. or 
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I meant to say, add an element to that array

Comment: Does this be helpful ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  this documentations they are no so helpfull. I have looked at this many time, i tried making the method async, but still can't get it working. This SetAsync, does not exist.

Comment: If want to use `SetAsync` , first need `DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("cities").Document("LA");` .Have you gotten the `docRef ` first ?